# SVN-move, creating a patch and keeping history after applying that patch later

Tags: svn, patch

I'm using TortoiseSVN.
Here's what I want to do:

```
1. Move some versioned files, keeping their history
2. Create a patch with these modifications
3. Revert my changes from (1.)
4. Apply the patch later
```

The problem is that I want the file history to remain (the file status after reverting and applying the patch to be the same as the file status after moving).

Comment: Patch files won't keep the move history. If possible, better do a commit in step 2 and revert that commit immediately again. That ensures you can restore the history correctly.

Comment: I want to commit only after step (4.). The revert at (3.) is local.

Comment: I understand that. But I don't know of any working alternate to do a commit-and-revert on the database, if you want to keep the history.